# Can I have two separate internet connections on the same line?

Tags: internet

If I have one line going into my house, and two activated modems from the same provider, do they each have their own bandwidth allocation? One modem is 100MBps, the other is 30MBps. The line is a COAX (cable) line.

Comment: …but the line speed you pay for is not dependant on the speed of the modem. My modem can do 300Mb, I only can have 150. My neighbours, on the same coax, get only 20, as they're on a different tariff. Adding a modem needs the engineer to 'dial it in' to the exchange, which he doesn't do via the modem. [This is on Virgin UK, ymmv]

Comment: As @JakeGould ends, only your ISP can possibly answer this.  Technically the physical cable won't be maxed out (as long as it's installed correctly and not 30 year old RG59), but there are many factors that put this question in the "only the ISP can say for sure" category, for example the answer may depend on whether the connections are paid for on the same customers accounts or different customer account.